# Cannot change screen brightness

Tags: brightness

I can't change the screen brightness on my laptop (Asus G53JW) with 12.10 installed. I have tried many ways to solve the problem, but nothing worked. I tried to edit grub with `acpi_vendor` and `acpi_osi` (I have tried all the combinations found on the ubuntu.org forum but still I can't change it. I even tried to add in `xorg.conf` the string:

> `Option “RegistryDwords” “EnableBrightnessControl=1″`

Nothing changed. The only way to get it to work is to use `nvidiabl` but I have flickering problems with it and I'd like to find a way to solve the problem without external modules like `nvidiabl`.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. In your questions to come, please do not add personal details and unneeded text like: "My English is no good". Many editors are here to correct English so there is no worry about your skills with the language. Please also tag the ***main problem***. The Brightness tag is most suited because you are experiencing problems with the *brightness*. Hope you have a great time on Ask Ubuntu! :)

Comment: Let me know if this works: "sudo setpci -s '00:02.0' F4.B=xy" (remove "s) where xy is a hex number. Try 5b, 40, etc for xy and let me know if brightness changes (Digits are 0, ..., 9, a(10), b(11), ..., f(15). Range is 00 - ff. 256 levels. Brightness value of xy = x*16 + y). I'm not sure that it'll work though without nvidiabl, but can't hurt to try. If it works, then you can map the command to keyboard shortcuts (after making it executable without requiring password).

Answer (score 1):

I have an Acer Aspire S7-191, installed Ubuntu 14-04 LTS. The brightness control, using the keyboard function keys, did not work  The following process resolved this issue:

1. Open Terminal with *Ctrl + Alt + T*
2. Type `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`
3. change the line which reads `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"`
4. Save and Close gedit.
5. Then update Grub with `sudo update-grub`
6. Then re-start

Answer (score 0):

Install [Brightness Controller](http://lordamit.github.io/Brightness/) with the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install brightness-controller
```

You can control brightness using its slider.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem, and found this:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness "X"
```

Where X is between 1 (full brightness) and 0 (backlight off)
Hope it helps :)