# Change brightness on Asus G53JW with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, brightness, asus

I have an Asus G53JW and I can't manage to change the brightness anyhow (fn hotkeys are not working). I used Debian for 6 months and had the same issue and never found I way around this.

I did search a lot before posting and the best I could get was [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149054/how-to-change-lcd-brightness-from-command-line-or-via-script) (by @raaz), but it is a workaround and only change the gamma, not the actual brightness (this type of solution killed my battery before).

There is [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227391/cannot-change-screen-brightness) other question regarding the same computer, but with no proper answer and it was related to 12.10, not 14.04 (my current version).

And I also tried xbacklight and brightness-controller without success.

Any idea? Thank you!

**EDIT**

It is really hard to find a solution: [here is the proof](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1946956). I've been search that long as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Brightness keyboard buttons do not work on Asus 1225c](http://askubuntu.com/questions/230609/brightness-keyboard-buttons-do-not-work-on-asus-1225c)

Answer (score 2):

Copy-Paste from here [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/230623/335321).

**First**

```
sudo sed 's/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="/' -i /etc/default/grub
```

**Second**

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot your system and see if Fn (for brightness) works.

By NikTh

Answer (score 0):

I really can't believe I found a solution for this after such a long time trying (way before I posted here...)

First, go to **Settings > Software and Updates > Additional Drivers** (this last one is a tab). Choose the official Nvidia driver (the latest and tested one).

Second, go to your terminal window and run `sudo nvidia-xconfig`. It will generate a `xorg.conf` file for you.

Third, go to that file and do as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/192090/121101) (quote below)

> This will open your X server configuration (after prompting for your password). You should see a section titled "Device" that looks as follows:
>
> ```
> Section "Device"
>       Identifier      "Default Device"
>       Driver  "nvidia"
>       Option  "NoLogo"        "True" 
> EndSection
> ```
>
> Append a line so it appears like this:
>
> ```
> Section "Device"
>       Identifier      "Default Device"
>       Driver  "nvidia"
>       Option  "NoLogo"        "True"
>       Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1" 
> EndSection
> ```

Lastly, restart you x server as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1222/121101) (quote below for lightdm. For the others is similar).

```
sudo restart lightdm
```

**EDIT:**

I just reused this method, and it worked again. For documentation purposes, my `xorg.conf` generated by `sudo nvidia-xconfig` was like this before including the "RegistryDwords" line:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection
```

**UPDATE:**

For those of you having brightness problems in Debian (I tested for Debian 8), the solution provided above also works, but first instead of going to the **Settings > Software and Updates > Additional Drivers** you need to follow the 4 steps mentioned [here](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#Debian_8_.22Jessie.22).

---

#### **EDIT *Mar 31 2016*:**

For Ubuntu 14.04.4, it is also necessary to do what Crowell says in his answer.